# Как узнать активные транзакции к базе у Fibdatabase?

Tags: база-данных, delphi, delphi-7, транзакции

Как узнать активные транзакции к базе у Fibdatabase ?

Answer (score 0):

не уверен на счет компонента (сомневаюсь что там это есть), но вообще инфо по транзакциям можно получить из системной таблицы MON$TRANSACTIONS.
Читать тут: 
https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref-appx05-transacs.html

Answer (score 0):

`TransactionCount: Integer;` - Свойство позволяет получить количество транзакций

`Transactions[Index: Integer]: TFIBTransaction;` - Свойство позволяет получить транзакцию по ее индексу

Источник: http://delphi-z.ru/fibfull-1.html